# Given the centroid, one vertex, and the angles of a triangle, how do you solve it?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, centroid

Assuming you know the angles of a triangle, but the only piece of information regarding scale that you're given is the coordinate of the centroid and coordinate of a single vertex (whose corresponding angle is known), is it possible to solve the triangle? If so, how does one go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct an arbitrary triangle with the given angles, construct its centroid and then use a similarity to map your initial triangle to the final one. The solution will be unique if you know the orientation of the triangle, otherwise you get two mirror copies.

Comment: You are only given one vertex, though, so what are the given vertices you speak of?

Comment: @Sheph: “angles” is what I meant; fixed.